# How to change the control flux variable of this method

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, control-flow

I have the following code:

```
function validateRule(product, rule) {
        let idx = 4, finishIdx = Object.keys(Header).length;
        let isValid = true;  //this is the control flux variable
        let ruleOptions = {};
        if (!rule[2]) return {valid: false, options: null};
        if (!categoryValid(product, rule[2].split(';'))) isValid = false;

        while (++idx <= finishIdx && isValid) {

            if (rule[idx] === "" || rule[idx] == null) continue;
            let tagName = Header[idx];

            let columnArgs = rule[idx].split(';').map(function(item) { return item.trim() });
            columnArgs.forEach(function(columnValue) {
                let resp = validateValue(product[tagName], columnValue);
                if (!resp.result) {
                    isValid = false;
                } else {
                    ruleOptions[tagName] = resp.options;
                }
            });
        }
        return {valid: isValid, options: ruleOptions};
    }
```

As you can see the method initializes the control flux variable 'isValid' to true, and I should change the initialize value into false but maintain the same logic, I have been stretching my head to find a solution without using an array, but I think its not possible right?

From what I understood isValid should be true if there isn't any value that turns out to be invalid (entering the block !resp.result).

Can someone help me out? I need the default starting value to be false, and only return valid true if its valid for all columnValues of all tagNames.

I think I need an array to store all the values valid state and then look if there is any value that is false, but was looking into a better way of doing it, maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

what about to return "false" from the function if you found an invalid value while looping the columns?

in this way if you found a value that is not valid you just exit from the function with the field valid at false, like this:

`return {valid: false, options: ruleOptions};`

if you reach the end of the function it means that all values are valid and you just return

`return {valid: true, options: ruleOptions};`

Comment: That's a good way, didn't remember about that, but returning inside the function of forEach doesnt work, I had to change to a for loop, thank you!